# Remove elements from ArrayList that are in another ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, collections

I'm having trouble deleting a collection of elements from an Arraylist. .remove() does not work for this situation.

I have the following arrayList called uncategorizedList that contains some information that I added with the following collection of elements.

```
List<ExpenseList> uncategorizedList = new ArrayList<>();
uncategorizedList.add(new ExpenseList("11/30/2017", "check deposit", 230.32));
uncategorizedList.add(new ExpenseList("09/12/2017", "cash deposit", 340.75));
uncategorizedList.add(new ExpenseList("08/01/2017", "edeposit", 30.01));
uncategorizedList.add(new ExpenseList("05/18/2017", "stephan", 1220.89));
uncategorizedList.add(new ExpenseList("03/02/2017", "bob", 20.50));
```

the next step is to take String[] income and see if uncategorizedList contains any of the words in String[] income.  If it does, I add the date, description, and price to incomeList.  The code works perfectly.

```
String[] income = {"edeposit", "stephan", "check deposit", "cash deposit"};
List<ExpenseList> incomeList = new ArrayList<>();

for (ExpenseList expense : uncategorizedList) {
     for(int i=0; i < income.length; i++) {
        if (expense.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(income[i])) {
          incomeList.add(new ExpenseList(expense.getDate(),expense.getDescription(), expense.getPrice()));


                    }
                }
            }
```

What I'm having a problem with is how to delete the elements from uncategorizedList that were added to incomeList.  As I stated earlier, .remove() does not work.  The only thing that should be left in uncategorizedList is `03/02/2017, bob, 20.50`

Comment: you might need Iterator for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Iterating through a Collection, avoiding ConcurrentModificationException when removing in loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/223918/iterating-through-a-collection-avoiding-concurrentmodificationexception-when-re)

Comment: @VPK I added the iterator and it's still not removing what I want.. check the edited post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the way you have used the Iterator is wrong. When you are using Iterator on `uncategorizedList` which has list of `ExpenseList`, `iterate.next()` will give you `ExpenseList` and not `String`. So try following code if it works for you:

```
for (Iterator<ExpenseList> iterate = uncategorizedList.iterator(); iterate.hasNext();) {
   for(int i=0; i < income.length; i++) {
        ExpenseList expense = iterate.next();
        if (expense.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(income[i])) {
            incomeList.add(new ExpenseList(expense.getDate(),expense.getDescription(), expense.getPrice()));
            // Remove the current element from the iterator and the list.
            iterate.remove();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works!!! you're awesome... at first I got a java.util.NoSuchElementException error but all I had to do to fix that is take ExpenseList expense = iterate.next(); and place it inside the first for loop...

Comment: I'm glad it did. Happy Coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to do something like `listName.remove(xx)`
Pass in the position as a parameter e.g

If you are removing using onLongClicks you would get position like this,

```
listName.get(position)
listName.remove(position)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do a little trick here by changing your sequence of loop like the following-

```
String[] income = {"edeposit", "stephan", "check deposit", "cash deposit"};
    List<ExpenseList> incomeList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < income.length; i++) {
        ExpenseList expenseList = new ExpenseList("", "", 0);
        for (ExpenseList expense : uncategorizedList) {
            if (expense.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(income[i])) {
                incomeList.add(new ExpenseList(expense.getDate(),expense.getDescription(), expense.getPrice()));
                expenseList = expense;
            }
        }
        uncategorizedList.remove(expenseList);
    }
```

or you could copy object from **uncategorilizedList** to **incomeList** and **removeAll** **incomeList** from **uncategorilizedList**.

```
        for (ExpenseList expense : uncategorizedList) {
        for (int i = 0; i < income.length; i++) {
            if (expense.getDescription().toLowerCase().contains(income[i])) {
                incomeList.add(expense);
            }
        }
    }

     uncategorizedList.removeAll(incomeList);
```

Hope it solves your problems :)

Answer (score 0):

By using contains() method of String class and removeAll() method of list interface the code can be written as follows:

```java
String income = "edeposit stephan check deposit cash deposit";
List<ExpenseList> incomeList = new ArrayList<>();

for (ExpenseList expense : uncategorizedList) {
    if (income.contains(expense.getDescription().toLowerCase())) {
        incomeList.add(expense);
    }
}

uncategorizedList.removeAll(incomeList);
```